# Diamond occur in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I was trying to check what java interface allows in java & I get some result

I am surprised that it allows inner class in java. and hence we can generate Diamond Problem easily. even if java have taken care for it.

What I have done is.

**MainInterface.java**

```
public interface MainInterface {


class MyTest{

        public MyTest(){
            System.out.print("AAAA");
        }
    }
}
```

**Test.java(interface)**

```
public interface Test extends MainInterface{
public void abc();

class MyTest{

    public MyTest(){
        System.out.print("AAAA");
    }
}
}
```

**Test2.java(interface)**

```
public interface Test2 extends MainInterface{

class MyTest {

    public MyTest() {
        System.out.print("BBBB");
    }
}
}
```

**Implemented class**

```
public class AllTest implements Test,Test2{

    public void abc() {

    }

}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AllTest.MyTest test = new AllTest.MyTest();// at this line it conflict.
    }

}
```

My Questions are what should be its solution ?
  2) why java allows to let it be?(as we all know java stops multiple extends because of diamond problem.)

Comment: How is this a diamond?

Comment: What kind of conlfict occurrs? IMO the class MyTest shouldn't even be visible outside ouf interface Test2.

Comment: sorry I miss one more interface.

Comment: `why java allows to let it be?` if you 've got that compilation error, it means java doesn't allow it.

Comment: I think the OP asks why it's ok to implement both interfaces.

Comment: @Kent of cource but I want to ask why java concepts miss over here.
as aioobe says

Comment: As you can read [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html#implementing-multiple-interfaces), you can implement multiple interfaces - why not?
There is only a problem with same method signatures in different interfaces. But I don't really know what kind of answer you expect...

Comment: @Maze, what problem is that?

Comment: @aioobe [quote from last link again](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html#implementing-multiple-interfaces) 
"a class can only implement at method with a given signature once"

Comment: Still don't see the problem if both interfaces have the same signature.

Answer (score 3):

Inner classes in interfaces are implicitly `static` (just like methods are implicitly `public` even if you don't use the `public` keyword).

Having said that, there is no conflict, and you can simply instantiate them by referring to them as:

```
new InterfaceName.InnerClassName();

// No error because InnerClassName is static
// And no instance of the "InterfaceName" is required.
```

Or if you import the inner class:

```
import com.somepackage.InterfaceName.InnerClassName;

...

// Imported, you can simply:
new InnerClassName();
```

### Why is it OK to implement both `Test` and `Test2`?

When implementing both `Test` and `Test2` interfaces, the (implicitly) static `MyTest` classes are still remain inner classes of `Test` and `Test2` interfaces and not the implementer `AllTest` class. It's just that if there would be no name collision, you could refer to them via the `AllTest` class too.

Analogy: If a superclass has a public static field, a subclass can refer to that as if it would be its own, but it still belongs to the super class.

Answer (score 2):

> *My Question is what should be its solution*

```
AllTest.MyTest test = new AllTest.MyTest();
```

should be either

```
Test.MyTest test = new Test.MyTest();
```

or

```
Test2.MyTest test = new Test2.MyTest();
```

> *why java allows to let it be?*

I don't really see the problem. As shown above, there's a trivial workaround.

Comment: what if i want to override that class in AllTest? at that time it makes some problem.

Comment: @PulahNandha There is no such thing as "overriding" a (static) inner class. Methods can be overriden only. The static inner class belongs to the declaring interface (see my answer).

Comment: oh sorry I forget that static thing cannot override.